# abbrev-mode - Expansion with trailing / does not work

Tags: abbrev

I want to have `w/` expand to `with` globally.

Defining the abbrev in the usual way works (e.g. typing`with C-x ag w/`), and the entry in the `abbrev_defs` file looks fine - output of `M-x list-abbrevs` under `(global-abbrev-table)`:

```
"with"         0    "w/"
```

However, typing "w/" in `abbrev-mode` or even manually trying to expand this using `C-x '` does not work. Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: Sorry, abbrev only allow sequence of English letters to be used as input. / can expand a abbrev like , or space...

Comment: @djangoliv Although "sequences of english letters" (word syntax in emacs terminology) behaviour is default, it can be customized. See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution without modification of the syntax-table.

From the GNU Emacs Manual - [Sect. 35.7 *Abbrev Table Properties*:](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Table-Properties.html)

> :regexp
>
> [...]
>
> If this property is nil, the default is to use backward-word and forward-word to find the name. This property allows the use of abbrevs whose name contains characters of non-word syntax.

I.e. it is only the default behaviour that non-word syntax is used to define the abbrev "boundaries", but this can be configured.

And indeed:

```
(abbrev-table-put org-mode-abbrev-table :regexp "\\(\\\\[a-z0-9@]+\\)")
```

lets me insert abbrevs with leading and trailing slashes in `org-mode`. (For other modes, or globally `org-mode-abbrev-table` needs to be replaced accordingly)

(With help from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3pi8wx/abbrevmode_expansion_with_trailing_does_not_work/ )

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on djangoliv's comment, "you cant'': abbrev's expands the last word and the "/" is not considered a word character.

Try this. Put this in a buffer:

```
abc/ def/ghi
```

and then move by word (Meta-F and Meta-B). You'll see that "abc" "def" and "ghi" is moved over, but we stop at the slash.

You can however modify what emacs-considers a word character via `M-x modify-syntax-entry / w`. Then when you move word you'll see that / is included in the word.

See http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable for more information on syntax tables.

Comment: That appears like a very radiacal approach to me. I would prefer a solution that woult not alter the behaviour which you demonstrate - i.e. `forward-word` and `backward-word` work as "shipped" by emacs.

Comment: @ChristianHerenz I was merely explaining the behavior and showing you how you could determine what is considered a word.  I was not necessarily suggesting you edit the syntax table. I should note that various modes that emacs uses _do_ in fact alter syntax tables. If you  feel that altering a global or local syntax table is radical, then djangoiv's comment holds: short of other equally radical approaches, you can't do this. Alter your abbrev.

Comment: To explain, why I dislike changing the syntax table in this way - then `forward-word` / `backward-word` messes up in path-names and URLs. The `w/` "mnemonic" I use since a long time in my note-taking - and I recently discovered abbrev mode - so I thought I could add a little bit of magic to my daily life by expanding this using abbrevs....  I'm sad to hear that it appears to be next to impossible.