# How to define abbrev boundaries and where to put them?

Tags: regular-expressions, abbrev

I'm new to Emacs and Common Lisp. I'm wanting to use `abbrev-mode` to replace standard Common Lisp function names with aliases that I have created. So for example, I would like to replace the following standard functions with my aliases:

1. `equalp`
2. `alpha-char-p`
3. `char<`
4. `char/=`

Following the example [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), I defined my abbrev table in the `global-abbrev-table` definition in the `abbrev_defs.el` file in the folder `~\emacs.d\`.

However, I discovered that it does not replace connected multi-words or words that contains non-alphanumeric characters (all except the first in my examples). Reading various [answers to questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17530/abbrev-mode-expansion-with-trailing-does-not-work#17539) here like this, things I need to do to fix this are:

1. Create a regexp that will define abbrev boundaries. 
   I want the regex to match any sequences of characters except white spaces, parentheses and quotes, so I came up with this regexp `\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)`, which I tested  using [`M-x re-builder`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#ToolsForConstructingRegexps) inside Emacs.
2. Modify the syntax table with the new regexp by adding the function `abbrev-table-put`.
   I came up with this: `(abbrev-table-put global-abbrev-table :regexp  "\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)" )`

After adding that sexp at the end of my init file, `abbrev-mode` is now broken.  It no longer replaces any word, but the default `abbrev-mode` behavior comes back if I comment out that sexp. Adding the sexp to either file `abbrev_defs.el`  or the end of file `abbrev.el` doesn't work.

Question: What's the right fix here? Is my regex wrong? Where should I put that sexp? Any other errors I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1, you need to test your regexp when searching **backward**, and there you'll see that Emacs will always end up matching just the empty string (which is the nearest match).   So you probably want a regexp like

```
"\\(?:^\\|[\t '()\"]\\)\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)"
```

so as to force Emacs to look further back all the way to the first char which is *not* part of the abbrev (even `"\\(?:^\\|[\t '()\"]\\)\\(.*\\)"` might work).

Nitpick for point 2: you're not "adding the function abbrev-table-put", which would mean defining that function.  Instead you're adding a *call* to that function.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your answer and it works on most cases, except for "char<" and "char/=".

Comment: I also tried "\\(?:^\\|[\t '()\"]\\)\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)\\(?:$\\|[\t '()\"]\\)" but did not work. Also, how do I test a regexp when searching backward, or forward inside emacs?

Comment: You can do `M-: (re-search-backward "\\(?:^\\|[\t '()\"]\\)\\([^\n\t '()\"]*\\)") RET`.  Maybe for `char<` you're hitting a problem in Emacs.  If so, this is the wrong place to discuss it, better report it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer, as it could probably be a bug. Cheers.